# slice a string column in Pandas using stop = value of a cell

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, slice

I am working with a data frame, and I have a text column that I want to filter to a new column ['text filtered'] using a str.slice method. The problem is when I use stop=df['len filter'] parameter, my code doesn't work. The `len filter' column contains the number of characters that I want to filter for each text.

```
DF['text_filtered']=DF['text'].str.slice(stop=DF['len filter'])
```

As result i got a full nan  'text_filtered' column and the next error:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

I tried using .loc but i can't solve the issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas

Comment: You gotta loop: `df.apply(lambda x: x['text'][:x['len filter']], axis=1)`